# Sharing files, and how to stay updated?

Tags: c#

I have a program I use on multiple computers, that I would like to keep in sync to each other.

The files shared are .json and .txt files. Am I just able to serialize back to the file every so often without cause for concern? The software is used to make transactions on an inventory, it is only used on 1 computer, and then I use the software to make purchases or restock the items after purchased. I just want to be able to access it from my computer without having to walk to the other computer, close it, and open it on my computer make my changes and close it, walk back and open it back up.

I haven't dug into this at all, as I'm not sure what exactly it is called that I am looking for.

I would think if I can just serialize back to the file it would be ok, but maybe there is an easy way to check if the file has been saved over since I have had it open on my computer?

Comment: Sounds like you need a database instead of files on disk

Comment: Seems like an easy thing to try. You'd just have to make sure you close the files once you're done.

Comment: Don't forget to back up your data periodically.

Comment: What would make the software on the other computer re-read the file if it is constantly running? When does the software on the other computer write the file? Syncing data that can be changed in multiple locations is not for the faint of heart. Use RDP/Remote Control instead of walking...

Comment: I originally had this software reading a datatable instead of the file directly. this was easier implementation, but as we all know the path of least resistance is not always the best path to follow. i dont plan on switching back though. My code is beginning to be a jumbled mess, and I have alot of cleanup to do, before I consider switching back. @NetMage I can add code that autosaves periodically I believe, or ser, deser at intervals so they are updating, at least this sounds like a easy fix in my head?

Comment: If you have multiple users editing a text file and are trying to update by overwriting it, you are going to destroy your data. If you have one user overwriting a text file containing JSON data and multiple users reading it, you are going to get out of sync or bad data on some readers. This is why databases were invented. Or you can implement locking on files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether or not the file was altered since some defined point in time look at the [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime?view=net-6.0#system-io-filesysteminfo-lastwritetime). If you have several computers running put the file on a shared folder and use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0). In general I think there is nothing principally not working with serializing/deserializing data to disc.

Nevertheless I would suggest backing up data and considering concurrency.

Comment: i will check out both the file system watcher, and also look into concurrency. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have setup a file system watcher to look over my directory. I plan to add some sort of save feature for when an update occurs. but I see an issue. if 2 computers are watching the directory for changes, and I change it on 1 computer, then the other computer will see this change so it will save over, which will change it. creating a loop. how would you handle a task like this? is this where concurrency were to come into play?

Comment: Updating a file on a computer should never trigger changes to the file. This must be avoided - unless you sync and make sure that no unterminated loop starts. Concurrency is an issue because files are not originally made for concurrent acess. You should be prepared to retry file operations.